# How to use a list of strings returned from a "Java Invoke" component in Tibco

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-business-works

Brief explanation.

In Tibco Business Studio, I have a "Java Invoke" component that consumes a Java class that should return an object List I have to manipulate it to iterate over it.

To iterate I am using an "Iterate" component with this configuration:

```
Name: Iterate
Group Type: Iterate
Index Name: index
Variable List: $JavaInvoke/MethodReturnValue
Iteration Element: currentElement
```

Nevertheless, the iterator doesn't make the iteration and it doesn't give a proper value to currentElement.

The Method Signature of the Java method is the next:

```
public static List<String> convertCsvToListJson(String file) {
```

What am I ignoring? How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " the iterator doesn't make the iteration and it doesn't give a proper value to currentElement"..... like how ?

Comment: I mean the Tibco component of type iterator

Answer (score 0):

Businessworks can iterate over a list but it has to be a list within a BusinessWorks object (defined by an XML schema). So in your case you likely need to convert you Java list of strings into an XML. You should be able to do it with the Java to XML activity. You would map the output of your function to the Input of this activity and should get an XML object containing a list in the Output. I'am not 100 % sure how this will behave so you would need to do some tests but in every cases you cannot iterate over a list in a Java object.

Comment: But that idea is defining a schema with the object structure. Right? Because we need to build a generic kind of object, that works with any kind of structure. Do you understand what I am saying?